# Why can we just plus two charge directly if they don't connect each other by a wire?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

Two concentric infinitely thin conducting spherical shells of radii a and b,where a<b,are charged to  potentials $V_a$ and $V_b$ respectively.The inner shell has a charge and the outer shell has a charge $2q$ .Find the electric field at R>b,R is the distance from the center.The figure is the fig A.

[image]

The solution from book is $\vec E=\vec u_R\frac{3q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}$,and my question is why can we just plus $q$ and $2q$ together,instead of ignoring the $q$ when we calculate the electric field at R>b?

because if we say the $\vec E=\vec u_R\frac{3q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}$ ,it seems that we calculate the electric field of fig B,and if we compare fig.A with fig.B,it seems that the charge of inner shell flows into the outer shell,so the charge become $3q$,but there is no wire which is connected the inner shell and outer shell in the fig.A,that is the reason why i wonder why is the $\vec E=\vec u_R\frac{3q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}$ instead of $\vec E=\vec u_R\frac{2q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^2}$ at R>b in fig.A

Comment: Are you familiar with Gauss' Law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric field outside a spherical shell with uniform charge $Q$ is the same as the field due a point charge $Q$ at its centre. This is a consequence of Gauss's law and symmetry. So *when outside both shells* in your Fig. A, the field is the same as that due to a charge 3$q$ at the common centre.

[Your Fig. B could be misleading, because (as shown by Gauss's law and symmetry) there is no field inside a uniformly charged spherical shell, whereas we know that there will be a field between the two shells in Fig. A, because you are outside the inner shell!]

Comment: so when fig.B is a uniformly charged soild sphere,is there a field inside the  solid sphere?

Comment: If we have a solid sphere made of an electrically conducting material, all the charge will (because of mutual repulsion) reside uniformly on its surface and there will be no field inside it. But if the sphere (radius $R$, charge $Q$) is made of an insulating material with the charge distributed uniformly throughout the material, there will be a field inside it. At a point a distance $r\ (<R)$ from its centre the field will be that due to a sphere of radius $r$ and charge $Qr^3/R^3$.